# How do I get a specific key in a nested map in terraform, when running in a for_each/for loop?

Tags: terraform

I have two sets of locals defined as below:

```
locals {
  env1 = {
    a = {
    }
    b = {
    }
  }
}

locals {
  env2 = {
    x = {
    }

    y = {
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I have to run a loop for local.env1 so that loop runs for a & b. But I also need "x" from local.env2 for a resource attribute in the same resource block the loops runs.

There are 2 resource blocks and it would look something like this:

```
resource_block1 
{
 for_each     = local.env1
 scope        = each.key
 id           = something["x"]
}

resource_block2 
{
 for_each     = local.env1
 scope        = each.key
 id           = something["y"]
}
```

For "id" attribute in both the resource blocks I don't want to hardcode "x" or "y" respectively. I want to programmatically fill "x" and "y" for "id" attribute in the respective resource blocks.

I tried to create a map for env1 and env2 I was able to fetch "a" and "b" from local.env1 but I am unable to fetch/filter only "x" or only "y" from it.

Any ideas/solutions please? Thank you for checking.

Comment: Please show the code that you tried and provide erros that you get.

Comment: the given structure is not capable of what you ask from it. what is the actual problem you try to solve?